# Confused about excercise with w/w%

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I found super simple excercise which is killing my mind. I should prepare 500 mL 1M HCl. I should make it from 36 w/w% HCl. I do not understand how I can make from less concentrated solution something more concentrated. Please, could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE. 36% HCl is "concentrated HCl", i.e. the highest concentration possible in aqueous solution. Have you tried googling "concentrated HCl"? You will find its molarity, then let us know if you are still having trouble.

Comment: :) Hello and thank you very much! That was the problem. Stepan

Answer (score 1):

You will solve this question, step by step.  Elements to bring together are

- starting with the concentrated solution, the concentration of 36 m% refering to 36 g of HCl per 100 g solution (acid) may be equally expressed in a molar concentration $c$:

$$ c = \frac{n}{V} $$

- The number of moles $n$ is the fraction of mass $m$ and molar mass $M$

$$ n = \frac{m}{M}$$

(You may check your result, the concentration of the concentrated hydrochloric acid should be similar to [here](https://erowid.org/archive/rhodium/chemistry/equipment/molarity.html).)

- The relation of concentration $c$, molar quantity $n$, and volume $V$ mentioned above may be rearranged.  For example, keeping the molar quantity the same, but doubling the volume of the solution will half the concentration. Keep in mind, the relationship described by the first equation is true for the concentrated solution, as well as for the diluted solution to be prepared, individually.
   By the same token, you know the solution *to be prepared* has to meet a certain volume, and a certain concentration.  So you could rearrange the first equation to determine the molar quantity of HCl necessary to prepare the dilute solution.

$$ n(\ce{HCl}) = \frac{c\,(\text{dilute acid})}{V\,(\text{dilute acid})}$$

- Now, you rearrange and subsitute the equations:
  $$ c = \frac{n}{V} \Leftrightarrow{} n = cV \\
  V(\text{concentrated acid}) = \frac{n\, (\text{molar quantity in dilute solution})}{c\, (\text{concentration in concentrated solution})} \\
  V(\text{concentrated acid}) = \frac{c\,(\text{diluted solution}) \cdot{} V\,(\text{diluted concentration})}{c\,(\text{concentrated solution})}
  $$

Try this on your own, *then* compare.

> By this calulation, you need 42.9 mL of the concentrated HCl to prepare 1 L of 0.5 mol/L dilute solution.

Let me suggest to you to try additional calculations of this type with different acids, different concentrations, etc., to get used to such calculations.  A molarity calculator like [this one](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/stockroom-reagents/learning-center/technical-library/molarity-calculator.html) may help you to check if you did correctly. Deviations in the results will occur, depending if (or if not) the calculation accounts for a density of the concentrated solution equal to 1 (like water), or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem was, that I forgot about CONCENTRATED Hcl molarity. Stepan